# Getting JFrame to contain JPanel

Tags: swing, user-interface, jframe, jpanel

I have a JFrame that I am sticking a JPanel into to display an image, in this case 1024x1025.  The problem I cannot seem to find an answer to is how to ensure my containing JFrame will display the whole image/JPanel.  I have something close to this example:

```
ImagePanel view = new ImagePanel(); //extends JPanel
JFrame Container = new JFrame();
view.setSize(1024, 1025);
container = new JFrame(winTitle);
container.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
container.setSize(view.getSize());
container.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
container.add(view);
container.setVisible(true);
```

The problem with this obviously is that the JFrame is decorated by the underlying OS, so I have no idea how many pixels to make it larger than the size of the JPanel from system to system.  As it is now, the image is cut off on the right and bottom by a handful of pixels each due to the setting of the JFrame to the same size as the JPanel.  Is there a way to tell the JFrame to read the size of the Jpanel it is containing and make itself large enough to display the entire JPanel?  Thanks!

**EDIT**

Setting preferred size on the image panels, then setting size (not preferred) on the container, then packing after the add gives me the behavior I was wanting.  Can anyone explain whats going on here, I still am a bit fuzzy on order of operations by some swing components.

Comment: *"JPanel into to display an image"*  Are you adding anything else on top of the image?  If not, put it in (an `ImageIcon` in) a `JLabel`.

Answer (score 0):

After the `container.add()` and before the `container.setVisible()`, add a `container.pack()`.

**EDIT:** You could also use `Box.createVerticalStrut(int)` and `Box.createHorizontalStrut(int)` in one of the sides of your BorderLayout. That should force the layout to leave room for the image.

Comment: That makes all the windows tiny, and they do not resize once I populate the image.

Comment: Then call `pack()` again after you populate the image.

Comment: I need the windows (JFrame) to be the correct size before the image is populated.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the image panel to the contentPane of the `JFrame`. And you should just use [`pack()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#pack%28%29) on the frame to make it take the appropriate size. It will take the size needed to accomodate the preferred size of its components.

Comment: That makes the windows tiny.  The JPanel does not have an image painted on its canvas at this point.

Comment: You need to set the preferred size of the enclosed JPanel, as pack computes the size of the frame based on the preferred size and layout of its components.

Comment: Ok, I think the actual problem might have been my Eclipse.  But this works, if I set the preferred size of my image panel, then setSize() on the container then pac()k it works.  If I set preferred on both it makes the frame small for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure about the Image resolution, then use `setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1024, 1025))` for the JFrame and also for the JPanel. Since JFrame uses `BorderLayout` by default, you dont need to specify `container.setLayout(new BorderLayout());`.

Comment: Unfortunately doing this makes the JFrame tiny for some reason.  I think it has to do with the pack();